# best practice for 301 redirecting www to non-www site

Tags: nginx, https, dns

I have been searching thoroughly about this but did not yet have a clear answer.

For example, say I have a domain `example.com`, and I want this to be my canonical URL (i.e. `www.example.com` should 301 redirect to `example.com`.

So this is what I did:

- DNS-wise

  - added an `A` record for `example.com` to the `server IP`
  - added a `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` as the alias for `example.com`
- webserver-wise (I used nginx if that matters)

  - has Upstream set to the `server IP`
  - redirect all `http` to `https`
  - redirect particular `www.example.com` with 301 request configuration like this: `return 301 $scheme://example.com;`

And then I tested with redirect checker such as [this](http://www.redirect-checker.org/), and got this result:

- `http://example.com` --> 301 redirect to `https://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com` --> 301 redirect to `https://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com` --> 200 OK,serving the content normally`
- `https://www.example.com` --> 301 redirect to `https://example.com`

This sounds like what I have been wanting to achieve, and opening all these 4 links on my Chrome browser did work. All of these links redirect correctly into `https://example.com` with all certificate being valid.

But if I try to check my site such as at [woorank.com](https://www.woorank.com/) or trying to making a request with Python3's `request` module they told me that the certificate of `www.example.com` is invalid.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
>>> r
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.id', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'www.example.com' doesn't match 'example.com'")))
```

This is because I did have only one certificate, registered with the domain `example.com`, and did use it for both virtual host `example.com` AND `www.example.com`.

So this is because I saw some reference on the [forum](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/1204#issuecomment-442961965) saying that:

> Another reason to use DNS is to avoid getting https for both domains.

What did I miss?

EDIT:

If this matters, I'm using the docker image `nginx-proxy` to automatically create a virtualhost. The certificate is signed as `example.com`, and I have both `example.com` and `www.example.com` configuration created as virtualhost.

Comment: You need a certificate that's valid for `www.example.com`. You could obtain one certificate for both domains, or use separate certificates.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! Do we really need to have different certicate to only do a 301 redirects ?

Comment: The redirect is passed over the `https` connection. The browser must first negotiate a connection to the server. The server can use any certificate, but most browsers will warn the user if the server uses a certificate that is not valid for the domain.

Comment: But this doesn't 100% click in my head because site like http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php are able to obtain the 301 redirects. Tested my domain there and it shows 301 correctly. Does this mean that the site didn't use `https` for its testing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment by Richard Smith, yes, turn out I just need to use SAN certificate for both `www.example.com` AND `example.com`. I don't know this was a thing.

Using SAN certificate, I'm able to create only 1 certificate for both type of domain.